# Flicker on DIV slide

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have this code snippet that is used to toggle div (slide up/down):

```
$('.menu').click(function () {
                var $clicked = $(this)
                            $('.menu').each(function () {
                                var $menu = $(this);
                                if (!$menu.is($clicked)) {
                                    $($menu.attr('data-item')).slideUp('slow');
                                }
                });
                $($clicked.attr('data-item')).slideToggle('slow');
 });
```

jQuery is included before it,

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

But, once the div slides down, some weird flickr shows (div slides down more than it should, it flickers and then its height becomes as it should).Sorry if i am not explaining this properly.

Console isnt showing any errors.
Any suggestions would help a lot!

P.S Jsfiddle https://jsfiddle.net/yz93a7h2/1/

Comment: please post all css properties of .menu

Comment: it isnt that, i tried playing with CSS as well. even if i completely strip my menu from all styling, same thing happens, menu slides more than it should, flickers and then its height adjust.
any chance my attached code is wrong?

Comment: no its a known issue as well. just want to make sure theres no position, overflow or height problem in your css. have you tried a newer jquery version? maybe they fixed it in a later version. yours seems pretty old i guess. If not possible to change it. use jquery .animate and animate the height.

Comment: that is the thing, i did tried the newer one, but there is another problem :D
when i include latest jQuery before the snippet, menu works properly, but other script on other page (its ecommerce site) stops working :D

Comment: If you add a small demo, we can see for ourselves without having to start producing all the basic code.

Comment: I apologize, here is the stripped example https://jsfiddle.net/yz93a7h2/1/

Sadly, it needs to be jquery version 1.7.2 because if changed, some other things get messed up

Comment: Any particular reason why you are using jQuery 1.7.2 instead of the most recent version?  @Thisandthat

Comment: Some other scripts on the site seem to be dependant on it, if i include latest version, a lot of things dont work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It has to do with the default padding of the `<h1>` tag.  You need to remove the padding to fix this.

Here's the CSS that I added:

```
h1 {
    margin: 0;
}
```

[jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/sohrab12/x951hx5t/)

Comment: this is what i tried at start, but it isnt CSS.Even if i strip all the styles from the menu, flicker still happens

Comment: Do you see the flicker in my jsFiddle?  @Thisandthat

Comment: i dont know did i wrote it before, if i include the latest version of jQuery, this works properly (but some other things on the site stop working), so i doubt it is CSS issue

Comment: Is that what you were looking? @Thisandthat

Comment: no, i meant that on my original page (i would link it, but it is unavailable to public - Bigcommerce site) if i include the latest jquery, flicker dissapears and the menu works properly, but if i leave it on the older version (1.7.2), flicker is there, so that is why i think it is js related.
your fiddle works properly, tried it few times

Comment: Maybe its something within jQuery that was fixed.  If the answer was satisfactory, could you mark it as complete/correct.   Thank you.  @Thisandthat

Comment: just one more, if i may. as you can see, i am complete js newbie, can you let me know is the code (for the menu) well written?